# Own implementation of System.Drawing.Image

Tags: c#

I want to create my own implementation of `System.Drawing.Image` but I always get `'Image' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`. `System.Drawing.Image` is an **abstract** class.

```
public class ImageYUV : System.Drawing.Image
{
}
```

I did take a look into the implementation of `Bitmap` but I did not find a solution...

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,80

Comment: When you create a subclass of another class, the constructors of the two classes are linked together (remember that all reference types have at least on constructor, if you don't write one, the compiler provides a default constructor for you). If you write a constructor (with or without parameters), that default on is not created. `Image` does not have a default constructor. Any `ImageYUV` constructor must, as a result, explicitly call a non-default base constructor. Your auto-genned default one doesn't do that. You need to explicitly write at least on constructor

Comment: What base ctor would that be?